# Running exec on apache in windows

Tags: php, android, apache, window

I am looking to send data from android device to the webserver and then execute a command using exc from server , i will be using apache , but i talked to a teacher of mine and he told me that he tried this thing some time ago but they were not able to run exec on apache in windows it was because web server didnt allow to rum executable despite of setting the permissions.

He said the same worked on linux perfectly , anyone faced the problem and its solution plus what if i use IIS as a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they were not able to run exec on apache in windows it was because
>   web server didnt allow to rum executable despite of setting the
>   permissions.

He is wrong. I use a lot of exe files (mostly for some specific function like extraction of the text from pdf files, or to trigger WOL for remote computer) on the development website under Windows and everything works perfectly. Everything depends on what current exe file is going to do and the rights of the system account under which the Apache service is running.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher was right. You'll need a linux server if your going to be doing any kind of dedicated tasks. Not to fear tho, Linux has thousands of software sources that you can use, and they should have all the tools you'll need to complete your project. Good luck.

Comment: the problem is i will be using a toolkit whose exe is available to me , and i have to use that exe in my project whereas linux dont support exe ofcourse

Comment: i am developing an online handwriting recognition and i have a toolkit of hidden markov model for this purpose but i checked i can run it on linux thanks for the help . i checked that windows allow to run exec through server if we make some changes in php.ini file